Add LC_CTYPE to Desktop Entry
I'm using fcitx5 with emacs, to enable entry of Chinese characters. There is a known issue with emacs, where in order to input Chinese characters, one needs to launch emacs using LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8 emacs. This works fine, but I would like to make this more permanent (for lack of better word).
One thing I would like to do is change the Desktop Entry file to set LC_CTYPE. The reason I want to change this file is because I have different symlinks pointing to it (like autostart), and would like to launch this entry with the edited LC_CTYPE. Is this possible?
My Desktop Entry file in /usr/share/applications/ looks like this:
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Emacs (GUI)
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=GNU Emacs is an extensible, customizable text editor - and more
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
TryExec=/usr/bin/emacs
Exec=/usr/bin/emacs %F
Icon=emacs
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility;Development;TextEditor;
StartupWMClass=Emacs
Keywords=Text;Editor;


One workaround mentioned here seems to be to use Exec=/usr/bin/env LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8 emacs %F.

Thank you @Arfrever Just to clarify, is that a one-line update to the Exec key's value? i.e., I should update Exec to LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8 emacs %F?

Try Exec=/usr/bin/env LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8 /usr/bin/emacs %F line. env tool (usually /usr/bin/env) allows to run any program with added/changed/deleted environment variables. See man 1 env.

I also remind that shell variables and environment variables are different things. env tool allows to set environment variables, whose names contain characters not allowed in names of shell variables: env -i my-variable:with@shell%disallowed^charactersあいうえお=1 python -c 'import os; print(os.environ)'.

Works perfectly. Thank you!

Note that your change will be lost when Emacs gets upgraded by your package management system. You should make a copy in ~/.local/share/applications, edit that instead and update your symlinks to point there.

Related: How can I get a .desktop launcher to use an environment variable?
